# How to pretrain BART using custom dataset(Not fine tuning!!)

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model, huggingface, bart

I'm using huggingface transformers 4.19.0
I want to **pretrain BART model using my custom dataset.**
To make it clear, I'm not asking about fine tuning BART to down stream task but asking about "pre training BART".

But I can't find method or class for this job on huggingface docs page (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bart)
Is it impossible to pretrain BART using transformers package?
Do I have to make BART model layer by layer from the scratch?

If anyone knows how to pretrain BART model using custom data please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize a random model with the architecture of your choice.

```py
from transformers import BartConfig, BartModel

configuration = BartConfig() # default Bart config
model = BartModel(configuration) # default randomly initialised BART
```

Then you need to train said model, the easiest way being using a Trainer ([doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer)), to which you provide your model, training sets, evaluation sets, etc.